# can't log in to django app using remote database. is the session broken?

Tags: database, django, session, authentication

IP address A (www.domain.tld) with a mysql database and a django installation is serving my webapp. everything is working fine.

IP address B (ww1.domain.tld) connects to the database of IP address A. and there is an issue.

- it's possible to connect to the BD using mysql-client (read/write) everything is ok.
- media are delivered as expected
- also the content will be read by the django application
- when i'm creating a new user account, the user will be created

BUT, it's not possible to log in!!

i assume there is an issue with the session.

who can i debug this, what could be the reason for this behavior.

thanks for all hints and support in advance.

phi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you logging in on www.domain.tld but then accessing the site via ww1.domain.tld? It may be  something to do with the [SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain) -- try setting `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".domain.tld"` in your server-specific settings.

Comment: This was exactly the problem! I had SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN (www.domain.tld) set - also the attribute HOST (www.domain.tld) was defined in the settings.py . I tried to log in from ww1.domain.tld which doesn't work of course... thx you very much!